# How to get the name of the row which is the mode in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Example:

```
  A    B
1 john 6
2 ryan 5
3 kate 8
4 paul 1
```

I want the formula that returns the text "kate" in A3, because the value in B3 is the highest in the range B1:B4. I would like to know also the same opperation but with the lowest value (i.e. B4 is the lowest, so I would get "paul").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the highest value you can use:

```
=INDEX(sort(A:B, 2, false), 1, 1)
```

This first sorts and then retrieves the value from the first row and column of the sorted data.

Using  the opposite sort order in the formula will yield the lowest value:

```
=INDEX(sort(A:B, 2, true), 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For unique entries there is no mode. A possibly more conventional but same length solution is, for `kate`:

```
=index(A:A,match(max(B:B),B:B,0))
```

and for `paul` change `ax` to `in`.

[INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
[MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378)
[MAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013)
[MIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094017)

For a very long list INDEX/MATCH might be quicker than a SORT.